# How can I copy a link id on a click using JS / React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

I have a link tag as follows:

```
<a onClick={this.linkClicked} id='some_string'>
  <svg className ='medd_link' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24"> ... </svg>
</a>
```

When the user clicks on the link I want the id 'some_string' copied to the clipboard.

How would I implement this?

```
linkClicked = (event) => {
  // const element = document.getElementById("myInput");
  // we are using react so we will work with the virtual DOM not the actual DOM
  // event.target maybe?
  // element.select();
  // element.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
  document.execCommand("copy");

  // why does event.target point to the svg element?
  alert("Copied the text: ");
}
```

**Update**

The first odd thing I noticed is that event.target points to the `<svg>` element and not the `<a>` element which I need access to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
onClick = (event, text) => {

  event.preventDefault();
  input = document.createElement("input");
  input.style="position:absolute;opacity:0";
  input.value = text;
  document.body.append(input);
  input.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  input.remove();
  alert("Copied the text: " + text);
}
```

```html
<a id='some_string' onclick="onClick(event, this.id)">click here</a>
```

Comment: Very nice,  but this is for React, should require some minor changes.

Comment: for react: `<a ref={ref => this.link = ref} id='some_string' onClick={event => onClick(event, this.link.id)}>click here</a>`

Comment: nice, I have not seen this ref property, is it unique to react, can you link to the doc for it?  Thanks!

Comment: yes, unique for react. take a look here: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Is it O.K. that event.target is pointing to the SVG element inside my A element.  I find that odd.

Comment: I don't understand why you are using ```ref``` just do ```e.target.id```

Comment: @Junius ... e.target is pointing to the SVG element for some reason and not the A element.

Comment: the target is the element that you click on, which was cause the event. because the `svg` is inside the `a` the click begin there. from there is travel up, from child to parent, till it reach the window. but the target is the svg

Comment: that makes sense ... implementing now.

Comment: You just need to add a this to `onClick()`.  For some reason the browser is saying that `input` is not defined.

Comment: Hmmm ... clicking is also making my page scroll ... not going to work as is.

Comment: It takes me to the very bottom of the page.  How can I disable this?

Comment: `input.focus` is causing this to happen.  Can your provide a work around?

Comment: Just removed it, it is not doing anything that I can see.  Works now.